# What would be the reason for my route not finding the page ID in pagination?

Tags: php, pagination, codeigniter-4

I'm using CodeIgniter 4 and I'm currently setting up a user list which is using pagination, filters and searches.

The pagination works in the sense of it's only displaying the limited amount of records however when I'm going to view the next page, it fails and says it can't get the route.

has anyone come across this before and know why is it doesn't work?

I've done the following code to create the pagination / user listings;

Please see code below;

Controller:

```
    public function hk_users_list_GET($page = 1)
    {
        $page = $this->request->getVar('page');

        // Find Logged in user
        $logged = $this->_admin_logins->fetchRequest(auth()->id());
        $me = $this->_user->fetchUser('id', $logged['logged_in_as']);

        return $this->hk_users_list_POST($page);
    }

    public function hk_users_list_POST($page)
    {
        // Find Logged in user
        $logged = $this->_admin_logins->fetchRequest(auth()->id());
        $me = $this->_user->fetchUser('id', $logged['logged_in_as']);

        // Variables
        $groups = $this->request->getVar('groups');
        $sort = $this->request->getVar('sort');
        $text_filter = $this->request->getVar('text_filter');

        $users = $this->_user->getAllUsers($groups, $sort, $text_filter, $page);
        
        if ( ! $users) {
            return 'No users found';
        }

        $filters = $this->hk_users_list_FLITERS();

        $all = $users['users'];

        $this->_data = [

            // Collected Data
            'me' => $me,
            'sess' => $logged,

            'users' => $all,
            'filters' => $filters,
            'links' => $users['links'],

            // Assets
            'assets' => $this->_assets,

            // Internal CSS
            'css_to_load' => ['admin/style.css', 'plugins/select2/select2.min.css', 'plugins/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.min.css', 'plugins/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.structure.min.css', 'plugins/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css'],
            // External CSS
            'ext_css_to_load' => [],
            // Internal JS
            'js_to_load' => ['plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js', 'plugins/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.min.js', 'forms/users/user_list.js'],
            // External JS
            'ext_js_to_load' => [],
            // Scripts
            'script_to_load' => [],
        ];

        return $this->_view('Housekeeping/users/list', $this->_data);

    }
```

Model:

```
public function getAllUsers($groups = null, $sort = null, $text_filter = null, $page = null)
    {
        $pager = service('pager');
        $page = (@$_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
        $limit = config('Syp')->pagination_limit;
        $offset = ($page-1) * $limit;

        $builder = $this->db->table('user_accounts u')
            ->select('
            u.id as user_id,
            u.username,
            u.status,
            u.created_at')
            ->join('group_users ug', 'u.id = ug.user_id', 'INNER')
            ->where('u.deleted_at', null);

        if ($groups) {
            if (is_array($groups)) {
                $builder->whereIn('ug.group', $groups);
            } else {
                $builder->where('ug.group', $groups);
            }
        }

        $users = $builder->get($limit, $offset)->getResult();

        $total = $builder->countAllResults();

        if (empty($users)) {
            return [
                'users' => []
            ];
        }

        $complete_users = [];

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $user_entity = new UserEntity((array)$user);

            $user_entity->group = $user_entity->collectGroup();

            $complete_users[] = $user_entity;
        }

        $return_data = [
            'users' => $complete_users,
            'links' => $pager->makeLinks($page, $limit, $total, 'default_full', 4),
        ];

        return $return_data;
    }
```

Routes:

```
// List (GET) and (POST)
            $routes->get(lang('Syp.url.hk.users.list'), 'Housekeeping\UsersController::hk_users_list_GET', ['filter' => 'isAdminLogged', 'as' => lang('Syp.url.hk.users.list_as')]);
            $routes->post(lang('Syp.url.hk.users.list'), 'Housekeeping\UsersController::hk_users_list_POST', ['filter' => 'isAdminLogged', 'as' => lang('Syp.url.hk.users.list_as')]);
            // List ID (GET)
            $routes->get(lang('Syp.url.hk.users.list') . '/(:num)', 'Housekeeping\UsersController::hk_users_list_GET/$1', ['filter' => 'isAdminLogged', 'as' => lang('Syp.url.hk.users.list_as')]);
            $routes->post(lang('Syp.url.hk.users.list') . '/(:num)', 'Housekeeping\UsersController::hk_users_list_POST/$1', ['filter' => 'isAdminLogged', 'as' => lang('Syp.url.hk.users.list_as')]);
```

Comment: I think we'd need to know abit about the lang() file situation. I also think you've spelt FILTERS wrong in your code.